# IIS/ASP.NET connecting to SQL Server using unknown user

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, authentication, impersonation

Defined a SQL Server, which only user x (in the domain) is allowed to connect to and only by using windows authentication.
I am connecting to the computer using user x successfully.
I am running my website from visual studio successfully.
But when I am trying to access my website on IIS it fails because it is using a different user than x:
When my ASP.NET web site is trying to connect it fails because it is using user y.
The connection string does not specify a user and password it uses windows authentication.
where did user y came from? is it the user that IIS was installed with or log on with?

The SQL Server is not mine so I cannot add users or change the authentication method there.

Is there a way that IIS/ASP.NET to impersonate (is that the term) user x?

Comment: IIS is running as Local System Account and also all the services that depends on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have **Integrated Security=True** in your connection string?

If so it's going to try to use the anonymous/IIS_USER account to access the DB instead of what you have in your connection string.

Comment: Yes, the connection string has "Integrated Security=True" but the user which is used is not anonymous/IIS_USER. But once I add to the web.config identity impersonate=true then the user is anonymous/IIS_USER even if I add to the web.config identity userName="x"

Comment: @kroiz Are you also passing the credentials in the connection string?

Comment: No, I did not. doing that, problem solved. :) Thanks a lot.
so to sum things up: in web.config we have the impersonation like this: <identity impersonate="true" userName="x" password="xxx"/> and in the connection string I also have user id and password.

Comment: am facing below issue while following above process.                                     **Not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied**.please help me